# Vakil's exercise 5.5.#

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'd like to check that my solution to the following exercise of Vakil's FOAG is correct. I am bothered that we have to use (B) in it, and I want to make sure that I used it in the end for the correct reason.

> 5.5.E. EXERCISE (ASSUMING (A) AND (B)). Show that the locus on Spec A of points
>   [p] where $\mathcal O_{\operatorname{Spec} A,[p]} = A_p$
>   is nonreduced is the closure of those associated points of
>   Spec A whose stalks are nonreduced. (Hint: why do points in the closure of these
>   associated points all have nonreduced stalks? Why can’t any other point have a
>   nonreduced stalk?)

(A) and (B) here are:

> (A) The associated primes/points of M are precisely the generic points of irreducible
>   components of the support of some element of M (on Spec A).
>
> (B) M has a finite number of associated primes/points.

My solution:

Let $\{\mathfrak n_i\}$ be the points with non-reduced stalks and $\{\mathfrak g_i\}$ the associated points with non-reduced stalks. We want to show the two containments of the equality

$$\overline{\bigcup \mathfrak g_i} = \bigcup \mathfrak n_i$$

By (B), the union on the left is finite, so we can rewrite this as:

$$\bigcup \overline{\mathfrak g_i} = \bigcup \mathfrak n_i$$

The containment "$\supset$" follows from: if $f \in A_{\mathfrak n}$ is a nilpotent, it is still a nilpotent on the generic point of its support ($f$ is nonzero on $\mathfrak g:= \operatorname{Supp}f$ by definition, and is contained in all prime ideals contained in $\mathfrak g$ since it is contained in all prime ideals contained in $\mathfrak n \supset \mathfrak g$).

For the opposite containment "$\subset$" note that if $\mathfrak p \in \mathfrak g$ and $0\neq \tilde f = \frac f b \in A_{\mathfrak g}$ is such that $a\tilde f^n =0$ for some $a\not \in \mathfrak g$, then $abf$ is also a nonzero nilpotent, and it lives in $A_\mathfrak p$.

Comment: Already there is a big mistake in how you went from $\tilde{f}^n = 0 \implies f^n = 0$....

Comment: @Benja, thank you for pointing it out! Now, I believe, the argument is right.